# what is the relationship between `CustomOperationAttribute` and the conventional CE Yield member?

Tags: f#, computation-expression, bolero

The excellent `ElementBuilder` [[GitHub](https://github.com/fsbolero/Bolero/blob/master/src/Bolero.Html/Builders.fs#LL111C42-L111C56)] of Bolero inspires me to try to share/centralize certain HTML-DSL expressions for reuse. So, in almost total ignorance, I start with this:

```ml
open Bolero
open Bolero.Builders
open Bolero.Html

type ElementBuilder with
    [<CustomOperation "bulmaStuff">]
    member this.BulmaStuff(n: Node) =
        div {
            attr.``class`` ["custom"]
            n
        }
```

and then I try this:

```ml
section {
    bulmaStuff span { text "wrap me" }
}
```

This does not compile. There is the error message:

```
Error: input.fsx (2,5)-(2,15) typecheck error 'bulmaStuff' is used with an incorrect number of arguments. This is a custom operation in this query or computation expression. Expected 0 argument(s), but given 2.
input.fsx (2,5)-(2,39) typecheck error No overloads match for method 'Yield'.
```

And, finally, there is this very helpful message:

```
Known type of argument: unit

Available overloads:
- member ElementBuilder.Yield: _comp: ComponentBuilder<#AspNetCore.Components.IComponent> -> Node // Argument '_comp' doesn't match
- member ElementBuilder.Yield: attr: Attr -> Attr // Argument 'attr' doesn't match
- member ElementBuilder.Yield: comp: ComponentBuilder -> Node // Argument 'comp' doesn't match
- member ElementBuilder.Yield: comp: ComponentWithAttrsAndNoChildrenBuilder<#AspNetCore.Components.IComponent> -> Node // Argument 'comp' doesn't match
- member ElementBuilder.Yield: comp: ComponentWithAttrsBuilder<#AspNetCore.Components.IComponent> -> Node // Argument 'comp' doesn't match
- member ElementBuilder.Yield: eb: ElementBuilder -> Node // Argument 'eb' doesn't match
- member ElementBuilder.Yield: fragment: AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment -> Node // Argument 'fragment' doesn't match
- member ElementBuilder.Yield: node: Node -> Node // Argument 'node' doesn't match
- member ElementBuilder.Yield: ref: HtmlRef -> RefContent // Argument 'ref' doesn't match
- member ElementBuilder.Yield: ref: RefContent -> RefContent // Argument 'ref' doesn't match
- member ElementBuilder.Yield: text: string -> Node // Argument 'text' doesn't match
```

My main question is, What is the relationship between `CustomOperationAttribute` and the conventional Yield member? The equally excellent [Scott Wlaschin series on CEs](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/computation-expressions/) does not cover `CustomOperation`.

Should I use `CustomOperation` like this in the first place? Should I avoid the advanced complexity of `ElementBuilder` and just made a seperate CE only based on yielding `Node` (elevating `ElementBuilder` to `Node`)?